# Matplotlib: How to increase size of bin in Heatmap (hexbin)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, heatmap, binning

Matplotlib: How can I set the size of the bins created using hexbin? The problem i have is that the bins are just much too small so that the graphic looks somehow weird.

Comment: Did you try playing around with any of the [optional keyword arguments](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin)?

Comment: @wwi Thanks for the quick reaction : ) Yeah, I did. For example setting the extent option somehow led to a Zero Division and the other settings did not seem to fit. So I am pretty helpless!

Comment: It is going to be hard for us to interpret ```the graphic looks somehow weird.``` and offer a somewhat non-wierd looking solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [pylab_examples example code: hexbin_demo.py](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/hexbin_demo.html#pylab-examples-example-code-hexbin-demo-py), you can easily play around with all of the optional arguments to see how they affect the same dataset.  Here is what `gridsize` does:

[image]

---

I just copy and pasted the code from the demo (including the data creation part) then made subplots with different values for the same parameter like this

```
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
plt.subplot(132)
plt.hexbin(x, y, cmap=plt.cm.YlOrRd_r)
plt.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
plt.title("Gridsize 100 (default)")
cb = plt.colorbar()
cb.set_label('counts')

plt.subplot(133)
plt.hexbin(x, y, cmap=plt.cm.YlOrRd_r, gridsize = 200)
plt.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
plt.title("Gridsize 200")
cb = plt.colorbar()
cb.set_label('counts')

plt.subplot(131)
plt.hexbin(x, y, cmap=plt.cm.YlOrRd_r, gridsize = 10)
plt.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
plt.title("Gridsize 10")
cb = plt.colorbar()
cb.set_label('counts')

plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Comment: Great, thanks : ) Do you also know how to prevent single bins from overlapping each other, that was one of the problems I had when changing the gridsize parameter.

Comment: @ketbra, I don't understand what you mean by ```single bins from overlapping each other``` - maybe you should post another question and include minimal example data and pics showing what you are trying to prevent - an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why are the hexbins squished in the above example? What causes some hexbins to stretch in either dimension? The ones above look too tall, for example and not a perfect hexagon.

Comment: @Cypridina - aspect ratio??